# Calling asmx webservice from c# app fails when the url is redirected to another url

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm calling a web service .asmx file in a Winforms application via a Proxy. I'm calling the domain a.mydomain.com
I've set up in cloudflare a redirect that points a.mydomain.com to b.mydomain.com

And if I try it out in the browser, everything is working as expected.

In my application, if I connect to b.mydomain.com (the new domain) everything works great but when I connect to a.mydomain.com I'm getting a System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException exception.

I got the impression that this is related somehow to the validation of the SSL certificate.
Any ideas on how to fix this (possibly without touching the code of the calling application)?

Thank you.